# eliminate / disable the page loading (animation) feature?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am building a page from the template purchased on Themeforest called: Truestory. I was wondering if there is a way to eliminate / disable the page loading (animation) feature?

http://themeforest.net/item/truestory-fullscreen-html5-template/3902394

here is the styles.css code what would I need to change/add?

Here is what I think needs edited correct? It is from Styles.css

```
/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*  PRELOADER
/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

#preloader{
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: 1;
}

.active-dock #preloader{
margin-top: -65px; /* dock.height/2 */
}

#preloader > span{
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
display: block;
width: 80px;
height: 80px;
margin-top: -40px;
margin-left: -40px;
z-index: 1;
background: url(../images/loading_small.gif) no-repeat center 15px #000;
-moz-border-radius: 99px;
-webkit-border-radius: 99px;
border-radius: 99px;
}

#preloader > span > span{
display: block;
margin-top: 40px;
font: normal normal 14px/30px 'Open Sans Condensed Bold', Arial, sans-serif;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;
color: #fff;
}

#preloader.landing > span{
background-position: center center;
}

#preloader.landing > span > span{
text-indent: -9999px;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If your question is about a closed-source product, consider consulting the official documentation. If you have access to the code, please post the relevant snippets in your question so that we can provide specific answers relating to that code. For more information, see [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: You can try to hide the element with a CSS stlye: `display:none`.

Comment: Here is what I think needs edited correct? view added code above

Comment: Well, if you expect 2.12MB of data to be downloaded fast enough to be able to not need a loading screen, then good luck to you! As for me, it took 12 seconds to load that page, and I am grateful for the loading animation telling me it was actually doing stuff.

Comment: what would you suggest I do to speed up the load time I have a test site up on Go dady account the account has about 3 site running on it. would using a different host make any significant difference in load times? www.gtlagentportal.com/ipadtest

Comment: @GeorgeCummins, that was an awesome response. I wish more comments on SO would be like that, especially regarding question quality. I see some incredibly snobby and snarky crud around here from time to time and it really puts me off.

Comment: I know, Right? Thanks Joseph!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want to hide the loading animation, you can alter the CSS to hide that element:

```
#preloader{
    display: none;
    ...
```

You can also consider removing the code that creates the preloader div in the first place. This may be a Javascript function, or it may be plain HTML in the template.

As Kolink mentioned in the comments, it is generally a good idea to notify the user that a long operation is in progress. The loading animation is a good way to do that. You can also consider improving the speed of the operation by optimizing the code or moving to a faster host.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the code below in the version v3.x of adminlite.

```
.preloader{
    display: none;
}
```